# Binding to a 2 dimensional array won't update after PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multidimensional-array, inotifypropertychanged

My grid contains an ItemsControl which is bound to a 2 dimensional array of Cells.

This ItemsControl ItemTemplate contains another ItemsControl which enables this 2-dimensional binding.

Eventually, each cell in my 2-dimensional array is displayed as an ellipse. Each ellipse's color is bound to a cell's enum property.

When I allocate the 2-dimensional array for the first time and set the binding's dataContext - It works fine.

However, after I update my array and raise my PropertyChanged event, the binding does not respond to this event.

I've read a little and one possibility for this bug is that my update process updates each cell's enum property only. This means that the 2-dimensional array is not re-allocated per each update, but rather changes it's cells inner data.

I did try re-allocating my array before the PropertyChanged was raised and the binding did work properly.

Could this be the reason? Should I really re-alloate or change my array's address per each update?

Below is my binding Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl Name="Board" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding 
                                    Path=GameBoard, 
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                    diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

This is the source property:

```
private Cell[][] GameBoard
{ get { return m_GameBoard;} }
```

And this is the manual PropertyChange raising:

```
protected void raisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Who is "updating" and where? Are you `raisePropertyChanged` in the individual `Cell`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer my own quesiton:

My most basic mistake was the usage of INotifyPropertyChanged. 
Since I am using a binding to a collection, I should have used the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

To solve my problem I've created a ViewModel for my 2-dimensional array. This ViewModel implements the ICollection and INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces, wraps my 2-dimensional array and by so -  this ViewModel is able to 'plug' into the binding properly.

Comment: Just a note on using `INotifyCollectionChanged`, it only triggers when the _collection_ itself changes, not when a property of an object in the collection changes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my case, the UI change should only occur after I've updated multiple properties in multiple items in the collection, and that's why I've decided to create my own custom collection ViewModel as I've mentioned in my answer. This ViewModel triggers the CollectionChanged on a customised timing. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I have come across many situations in WPF where it is necessary to raise the `PropertyChanged` event outside of property setters. I believe that your situation may well be one of those situations. Changing the actual cell values do not affect the array property and will not raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

In these situations, not only is it perfectly acceptable, but it is even necessary to raise the `PropertyChanged` event manually. By this I mean the following:

```
Array[0,1] = newValue;
NotifyPropertyChanged("Array"); // Your method may have a different name
```

Try this and let me know if it helped.

Comment: I already do manually raise this event out of the property's setter... please see question's edit. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From the [ItemsControl.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) MSDN documentation:

```
Note that the ItemsSource property supports OneWay binding by default.
```

Therefore, you have to set the `Binding Mode` to `Two-Way`.

```
<ItemsControl Name="Board" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding 
Path=GameBoard, Mode=Two-Way,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

Comment: The way I understand it, TwoWay Binding mode enables UI changes into my source collection. This is not what I am trying to achieve. If you are interested, I've posted the solution I had managed to find after some further research. Thank you :)